# E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing

Tags: java, libgdx

when i try to use `.gif` image in my project this error comes out:

> E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long;
>   assuming deadlock and killing

what I'm suppose to do in this case

```
playButton = GifDecoder.loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP, Gdx.files.internal("settings.gif").read());
```